# Which Function we need to use In Data Stage Transformation for DATE from the Month

Tags: date, etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

Populate the first day of the current month, this field will be populated only monthly for table name file only in format YYYYMMDD e.g. in June this will be '20190601'

Comment: please provide more details - I am not sure what exactly you are asking for...

Comment: Hi, @MichaelTiefenbacher Thanks for your reply. My point of the question is from "CurrentDate" last 2  (dd) digits should always '01' from the current month:    Ex:  2019-03-01.       Here always 01(dd) should come.  Hope it may give a bit of clarity. if not plz let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the "01" as first of each month could be done in a transformer with the help of string functions. Your Date is in the  format YYYYMMDD
so try it with [1,6] which will give you basically YYYYMM and ad the "01" through a concat.

This could look like this:

```
to_tx.datecol[1,6] : "01"
```

Comment: @hrveeraIf it fits your requirement please mark it as answer